# Measure to get data for previous date available

Tags: date, dax, measure

I have a power bi and I need pretty much the same measure for each.

For the dataset, I have a table 'Data' with Columns [Date], all unique dates, and then columns with values, each column is a item with prices at those dates. ex: Columns: [Item A], [Item B] and so on.
I have around 50 columns of items. The column [date] has all the date except for weekends days and holidays because it work with an API and prices aren't available at those date.
I have a second table 'Date' with all the dates and all the items columns, same as table 'Data'.

What I need is a measure in a new column to lookup all the items prices at the dates available and if the date is not available, then I need the previous available date prices.
ex: it was an holiday on Friday, then I need the Friday, Saturday and Sunday to retrieve the price of the previous Thursday. If date is available, then take the date price.

Thank you!

I simply tried lookup values but I can't seem to understand the logic on how to get the previous date available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in PowerQuery and simply "Fill Down".
Select all "Item" columns, right-click on a column header > `Fill` > `Down`.

[image]

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

### Additional

Use the following in a query to create consecutive dates from the first to the last of your "data api" query.

```
let
    Source = #"data from API"[Date],
    DatesList = List.Dates(
        List.Min(Source),
        Duration.TotalDays(List.Max(Source) - List.Min(Source)) + 1,
        #duration(1,0,0,0)
    ),
    DatesTable = Table.FromValue(DatesList, [DefaultColumnName = "Date"])
in
    DatesTable
```

Then from there, do a Merge, and then Expand.

- In this new Query, select `Merge Queries` in the Home tab in the ribbon, under the `Combine` group.
- In the window that pops-up, click on the `Date` column, then select your data api query in the dropdown, and select the Date column there. Then hit OK.
- Finally, Expand the new Column to get all the other data columns.

For more details/help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-overview

Comment: I thought of that but the 'data' table with the api does not show the weekends days nor the holidays, so I had to create another table with dax and then it will not show in power query so the fill down method was not an option to begin with unfortunately

Comment: I got you. I've updated the answer above with **additional**.

Comment: so far it gives me all the dates I need but not the other columns with all the data like column Item A etc, how do I add them?

Comment: Added more to the answer above.